# SQL Percentage from two queries

Tags: sql

Currently I have a stored procedure that gets the amount of data mapped and total (in two columns) but I'm struggling to add a third column with a percent.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT 
    (SELECT SUM(Length) / 1000
     FROM [dbo].[map_cache_main]
     WHERE Gradient IS NOT NULL 
       AND TRID >= 1000 AND TRID < 3300) AS Mapped,
    (SELECT SUM(Length) / 1000
     FROM [dbo].[map_cache_main]
     WHERE TRID >= 1000 AND TRID < 3300) AS Total
```

Current output:

```
21681.8478879079, 31293.9302964378
```

Desired output:

```
21681.8478879079, 31293.9302964378, 69.28%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this all in one query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Gradient IS NOT NULL THEN Length END) / 1000 as Mapped,
       SUM(Length) / 1000 as Total,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN Gradient IS NOT NULL THEN Length END) * 100.0 
        SUM(Length)
       ) as percentage          
FROM [dbo].[map_cache_main]
WHERE TRID >= 1000 AND TRID < 3300;
```

I don't see why you would both wrapping this logic in a stored procedure.  A function or view would also be appropriate.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with SQL functions but I'll look into it. Thanks!